# Multiple conditions for AND and OR in WHERE clause SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

I am working in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I have multiple tables I'm working with and multiple conditions (nearly 80) that I am querying on where I am trying to achieve a subset of joined data.

The idea is that I need to grab data from a join, where that data is not in a different join based on a condition (i.e., `NOT IN`), then I need to filter on a bunch of conditions involving multiple columns and multiple conditions on each column. My problem (I think) is arising from the `OR` condition. I have a column, say `col5`, where if it doesn't satisfy any of the conditions in the `AND` condition, then I need to filter further on it (hence, the `OR` condition).

What I have written so far is the following,

```
SELECT 
    handfulOfColumns
FROM 
    table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM table2
     WHERE col2 = 'thing0' or col2 = 'thing1') AS t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
WHERE 
    t1.col1 NOT IN (SELECT t1.col1
                    FROM table1 t1
                    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.col1 = t3.col1
                    WHERE col3 LIKE '%thing3%')
    AND (col4 > '#' AND col5 NOT LIKE 'thing4' 
         AND col5 != 'thing5' AND col5 NOT LIKE 'thing6' 
         AND col6 NOT LIKE 'thing7'
         --...
         --... add like 20 lines of conditions similar to above
         --...
         AND col34 NOT LIKE 'thing77' AND LEN(col35) > '#')
     OR (col5 NOT LIKE '% %' AND col5 LIKE '%[a-z]%' 
         AND col5 NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
         AND col5 NOT LIKE 'thing209' 
         AND col5 NOT LIKE 'thing210');
```

The reasoning for this is I have a lot of (messy) phone numbers I am dealing with in `col5`, and overall there is a lot of cleaning to be done on all the columns. Some of these phone numbers will have text entered instead, and depending on the context I may want to keep them or filter them out (i.e. cases where the phone number is entered as 'business name', or 'business', or 'alskfjalsdkjf', rather than '555-5555' or '555 5555' etc). If the data meets the criteria of the `AND` conditions (mainly filtering out variations of `col5 not like '%555-5555%'`), then I need to further check and filter for any non-numeric characters in `col5` through the `OR` condition.

There are no error messages - instead the query takes a really long time to finish and gives me more rows of data than I started with which is the opposite of what should be happening. Based on the structure of `table1` and `table2`, there is potential to introduce duplicated rows by joining the two tables, but the amount of conditioning and sub-setting I am doing should give me far less than the original number of rows even with a few duplicates here and there.

I am not sure where my logic is failing for this, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: fix the sub query in your left join, if its returning more values than what you originally had, then that subquery is returning duplicates.

Comment: The thing is, if I run just the join part of this I get roughly 64K rows of data (which would be including the duplicates, as `table1` alone has about 60K rows of data) . But then when I add on all the of the conditions starting with the `WHERE` clause, I end up with about 67K rows of data - where logically I should end up with under 64K. So even accounting for duplicates it's still returns a higher amount than anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

Other than than proper syntax corrections marc_s suggested, this actually runs just fine. Turns out I had a couple condition statements incorrect in the `AND` condition (i.e. a few `=` where logically they should have been `!=` and `like` where they should have been `not like`) but the overall structure and logic is sound - reran on a couple test databases and it's working perfect. Apologies if this gave anyone a headache :)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks quite messy, even if it provides the correct results. In order to make queries more readable, I would try the following:

1) If you are allowed to add some columns to existing schema, you can add some meaningful columns that can be reused in queries. Your table could look like this:

```
create table table1 
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    col1 VARCHAR(64),
    col2 VARCHAR(64),
    col3 VARCHAR(64),
    col4 VARCHAR(64),
    col5 VARCHAR(64),

    Thing4Like AS (CASE WHEN col4 > '#' AND col5 NOT LIKE 'thing4' THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END) PERSISTED,
    Thing56 AS (CASE WHEN col5 != 'thing5' AND col5 NOT LIKE 'thing6' THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END) PERSISTED
    -- other columns may come here
)
```

This allows you to write much more readable queries and even make the queries faster, as some information is precomputed. Also, persisted columns allow indexes.

2) If you cannot alter the schema, you can create a view over table1 containing extra logic as presented above. For extra performance, they can be [indexed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Even though it works I figured what I had written is fairly messy and could be improved upon.  I'm relatively new to SQL and have only started using it recently, so I'm always looking for a way to clean things up a bit.

Comment: If possible, try to write things as readable as possible, otherwise you or a colleague will hardly understand what is going on after several months. This applies to programming in general, not just SQL.